# Multiple versions of tested app tested by one JUnit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Our app is as follows:
[Frontend] <-restAPI-> [Backend]
Backend supposed to be always at the latest version and can support multiple versions of the frontend, like Ver1, Ver2, etc. There could be minor changes in the restAPI protocol or even how the frontend reacts (more function or different behavior).

This test project tests correct communication, how the frontend behaves and backend for serving right data.
We would like to have the same test project branch to be used for all supported versions, right now there are really only minor differences so our java test code have

```
if (version == "ver1") {
    ....
} else if (version == "ver2") {
    ....
}
```

Question is what is the most elegant way to split the versions ? Right now it works, but as version number will rise it would became a mess.
I thought like to have a parent @Test method and decide which child test to run according to the version.

```
BasicTest.java
BasicVer1Test.java
BasicVer2Test.java
```

Question is if my idea is good, maybe somebody faced similar problem.

Comment: Personally, I would probably write one test per version and move all the stuff that's the same of all versions in a base class, so that only the things that are different are tested in the version specific class.

Answer (score 1):

The responsibility of your "test system" is **testing**. Not version control.

In other words: the "correct" answer here is to use a source code management system!

Your code base contains

A) source code
B) associated tests

So, when your product has several distinct versions, than should be managed by having A) and B) *together* within same branches.

Whereas your setup seems to be that those aspects are really separated; and your "test code base" is **not** in the same way version controlled as your product code. That is the crucial point to address.

Anything else is just fighting symptoms!

[EDIT] To add as example

```
Branch 1 - Version 1
    Source for Version 1
    Tests for Version 1
-------------------------------
Branch 2 - Version 2
    Source for Version 2
    Tests for Version 2
```

When new versions add more function or change behavior, it should be tested separately and its source should be maintained separately!